# How to decompress multiple .tar files on a remote file with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I decompress a `.tar` file on a remote file using PHP:

```
<?php 
$server   = "host"; 
$username = "usr"; 
$password = "pass"; 
$command = "tar -xvf 
/tmp/test/OK_MemExpFile_UPA_519_99_1_2509_20180403135101.tar";
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);
?>
```

The problem is that I want to decompress multiple `.tar` files. I tried to run a bash script with PHP but `tar -xvf` doesn't work. Here is my bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
vardate=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
base_path='/tmp/test'
echo "Start proccess merge file DSP!";
cd ${base_path}
cat ${base_path}/*.tar | tar -xvf - -i
rm -rf *.tar
ls -ltr *.csv | awk '{print $9}'| while read i; do sed -i '1,5d' $i; done
cat *.csv > dsp_baselinedaily_${vardate}.csv
rm -rf MemExpFile*.csv
mv dsp_baselinedaily*.csv ${base_path}/dsp_raw/
echo "Finished Merge File to dsp_baselinedaily_${vardate}.csv !"
```

and I execute that with PHP:

```
<?php
$server   = "host"; 
$username = "usr"; 
$password = "pass"; 
$command  = "/usr/bin/bash /tmp/test/mergedspfile.sh";
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);
echo "Mergefile Process already finished !" . '\n';
?>
```

What should I do?

Comment: It's far from clear what works and what doesn't work. Firstly, accessing the tar archive, does that work? Secondly, you mention decompressing, so I wonder whether it's important at all that the file contains a tar archive. In other words, does the whole work with other compressed files? Please also make sure that you read [mcve], it gives some advise how to solve problems by reducing the scope.

Comment: Btw.: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)